# React -how to check off items in todo list?

Tags: reactjs

I have a todo list and I want to apply css (strike through) on checked off items, not just delete them (also store checked value) but cant figure out how to properly do that. Any ideas would be great!! On a side note, I know its not a best practice code review place, but any opinions regarding my code structure are super welcomed, as Im trying to improve! Thanks!!

```
class TodoWrapper extends React.Component {
    state = {
        todos: [],
        currentItem: {text: "", id: "", checked: false}
    };

    onChange = (input) => {
        this.setState({
            currentItem: {
                text: input,
                key: Date.now() / Math.random()
            }
        })
    };

    addItem = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const newItem = this.state.currentItem
        if (newItem.text !== '') {

            const todos = [...this.state.todos, newItem]

            this.setState({
                todos: todos,
                currentItem: { text: '', key: '', checked: false },
            })
        }
    };
// here I could delete them but I dont know how to not delete and just mark checked (with strike through css)
    deleteItem = key => {
        const filteredItems = this.state.items.filter(item => {
            return item.key !== key
        })
        this.setState({
            items: filteredItems
        })
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <AddItem
                    addItem={this.addItem}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    currentItem={this.currentItem}
                />
                <List
                    todos={this.state.todos}
                    handleCheck={this.handleCheck}
                    deleteItem={this.deleteItem}
                />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}



const AddItem = ({addItem, currentItem, onChange}) => {

    const onInputChange = (event) => {
        onChange(event.target.value)
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={addItem}>
            <input value={currentItem} onChange={onInputChange}/>
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
    )
};

const renderList = todos.map(item=> {
        return (               
                <li key={item.id}>{item.text}
                 <input
                     type="checkbox"
                     checked={item.isChecked}
                 />
                </li>React - h
        )
    });

    return (
        <ul>
            {renderList}
        </ul>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd create a class or style based on whether item.isChecked.

e.g.

```js
<li key={item.id}>
  <span style={{textDecoration: item.isChecked ? "line-through" : "none" }} > 
    {item.text}
  </span>
  <input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={item.isChecked}
  />
</li>
```

Comment: thank you. my question was mostly regarding how to I update my todos array with the item being checked off. sorry if I wasnt clear enough

Comment: As the todos state is an array of todo objects, your `handleCheck` will filter the `todos` state and update the `isChecked` property to true on the target item.

[React Form Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs) have a clear example.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late but as this is a very common pattern here a possible solution:

```
handleCheck = key => {
  const todos = this.state.todos.map(todo => {
    if (todo.key === key) {
      return {...todo, checked: !todo.checked}
    } else {
      return item
    }
  })
  this.setState({...state, todos: todos})
}
```

The idea here is to directly map the current state to the new state and only toggling the `checked` property when the key is matched. This also allows for checking and unchecking with the same method.

---

Note: I'd strongly recommend to have 2 separate state variables for `todos` and `currentItem` instead of one generic `state` combining the two.